# Microsoft ODBC driver for Oracle Instant Client

Tags: sql-server, oracle, odbc, oracleclient, instantclient

I am new to Oracle databases, and I was wondering if you could install a Microsoft ODBC Driver (or any ODBC Driver) for Oracle instant client? I am unable to run the Oracle instant client ODBC driver install, because my computer cannot recognize the source (this is not my own PC). Thanks!

Comment: You only mention Oracle in you question, but you have tagged SQL Server? Why?

Comment: Please state what you are looking for, what you have tried and what went wrong. Otherwise it gets really difficult to help you.

Comment: Hi! I am using this to connect to a remote Oracle  database. I am trying to install Oracle instant client, to be able to use those libraries for sql, C++ and python database programming. I have checked the installation instructions  and they require an ODBC driver. I cannot install the Oracle ODBC driver (I have tried to do it through admin on command prompt, and I’ve tried to open the file, but the error I’m getting is that it is blocked by my company because it is an unverified source- I can’t get around that). So I’m looking to install another driver

Comment: What OS do you have?

Comment: I have Windows 10, but I was able to resolve this!